# Typescript losing generic context on function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am working on a query builder and running into issues where the builder loses it's generic type information when created as a function within the scope of another context.

The builder is responsible for "building" a table specific query, while the context is tracking the current state available to the builders, allowing for things like projections to be added in dynamically (CTE style queries).

Context gets passed to another component that can materialize the query (it's stored as AST under the covers) hence tracking the projections and type information that was removed from earlier more complicated example.

```
type Database = { tables: Record<string, Record<string, any>> }

interface DummyDatabase {
    tables: {
        "foo": { id: number, name: string },
        "bar": { name: string, "type": number }
    }
}

class Builder<D extends Database, T extends keyof D["tables"], C extends keyof D["tables"][T] = keyof D["tables"][T]> {
    columns?: C[]
    table: T

    constructor(table: T, columns?: C[]){ this.table = table; this.columns = columns}

    select(...columns: C[]): Builder<D, T> {
        return new Builder(this.table, columns)
    }
}

class DatabaseContext<D extends Database> {
    from<T extends keyof D["tables"]>(table: T): Builder<D, T> {
        return new Builder(table)
    }
    with<A extends string, T extends keyof D["tables"], R extends Record<string, any>>(alias: A, builder: Builder<D, T>): DatabaseContext<{ tables: { [key in keyof D["tables"]]: D["tables"][key] } & Record<A, R> }> {
        // Track alias and builders that provide for future use, that's why params are here above, leaving out for brevity...
        return new DatabaseContext()
    }
}

function from<D extends Database, T extends keyof D["tables"]>(table: T): Builder<D, T> {
    return new Builder(table)
}

const a = new DatabaseContext<DummyDatabase>().from("foo").select("id")
const b = new DatabaseContext<DummyDatabase>().with("no", from("bar").select()) // <-- Lost intellisense...why?
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAjOBnaBeKBvKikA2EqAXFAEoQDGA9gE4AmAPKsHQJYB2A5gDQXV6zVhx784nEAD4pUAL4AoBV2AQ6AMzhVoMAK4BbfSHj400bAqhW8yIqRyXrTgETqaNZ2VzsGZTgaQ1fk44fQgyES5ueV5HJytnFDpPHCgQsIi2KP5nUEgU-31Aunk40sUFKgI0VCgAIV12AgY1JhgoCAAPVU4GWpNkM34AFQ7uiF7agGsIEBp1WABtXNtiZwBdfgBhMZ6+qBm5hZhl-DsNxeH1qCxD+aWVwjX1y-XZCydaAgNOVAB+MhbRbrMpncJQYZKT40X5sXRUYD0AAUYLIw34Xx+-0BwIAlLhgAALdioAB0YJuNieAG48MSyZj9L9KYzfhUnOgiAikaTeaz7ED1riyA0mi06G0Ru8yk46BBgLo6Jw0hAAO71RrNNQo+nk1YYmjfJmoXFlRQVKo1WAIQboLYw1TdNq7Cb7AYodDSpzqOg0fRMUZdPbTWb3E6Pc5vFGrNHCjVi1owKUOeLWOUKpUq9WirV0aNPU1ORROVXsIlMACCLsmUEiYgh1f2d2Op1WqA2-HIjdqlFojBYWXrEmkUiRcAI7DQZAr-CQmvFIvnialcfdZntnEdwCYBLbXigi0OUC4B1DLYjz3WZHDYPbL0O1zkUAAZAI+8wZxRZHIvamoAB6f8IToLQpigcdJ1qCQGCgOcEzoWoiQQKAwF9AA3HxoDcEp1F0DNoF0dB+CQ4AAHJalVQkQBQuAQP0KC5SgQk1GgZAaDQiB+CIOAMJ4KAaDwqBsNguUMNAXlSRlNN5UVZVODVa1TDtB0gyRQtrHNJRcM4BF2BhITfX9dog1dfobQ9TiGxMmtmweW8NlHVEITjHNxUlCFfysdNZKzeNc3zIhTQtGFWHAyl5PVNdlM3IM2gMIwoogUdcVJH0-SRVx3GcFLOWoYAMp8bLKhC4BYPChTEo3Lc4sMYxzLMZLSVLIkMs4Dx+DS-QMqSbLSVy7lcVxACgKYABaUaoAAGRoUKVAgAgJ3QX4IAkyiQD+IA)

My expectation was that the fact that it inferred that the builder had a specific table binding to it, that I could then get the columns correctly since that object obviously has to be bound to the given table with those signatures, but as soon as I try to add the `select()` call it can no longer handle the bindings which doesn't make sense since it *should* keep the same `Database` type

Edit:

While I can force usage of the context object itself to generate the from, I don't understand why the function itself doesn't providing the bindings unless I explicitly add them via `from<DummyDatabase, "bar">("bar")...` but it already can detect that `from("bar")` is inherently equal to `Builder<DummyDatabase, "bar">` but the select forces it to drop that knowledge when that should be returning an equivalent `Builder<D, T>` based on the signature...

I'm using typescript 5.4

---

Seems that this isn't possible to keep the context across the calls this way as TS can't look far enough back up the chain to get it beyond just the basic `context.with("foo", from("bar"))`.  Just means I need to be careful with any nested depth, will mark the explicit version as the answer though it seems rough that I can't get it without having to pass those hints =\

Comment: There's a lot going on here; could you try to whittle it down more to a manageable [mre] that fits on a screen at once? Do you really need separate classes and the interfaces they implement for this example? Does the problem not show up with just the classes? Like, right off the bat, I'd reduce it to [this version](//tsplay.dev/mZ5RoN). And wonder why `Builder` cares about its third type parameter when it doesn't do anything with it. And wonder why `from` cares about its first type parameter when it can't possibly infer anything for it. Could you [edit] and address these so we can proceed?

Comment: Updated to a hopefully more simple version, thanks!  The Builder cares later because I can project a subset of rows and want to track that type info but it's not really part of the issue as I can still reproduce with the above, so removed it for now.  The from function only has the first parameter so I can keep the context of the table it's selecting columns from and it needs to know that type info from the original database source (I thought...)  For the class method, Database is already known from class binding but for global function I have to get elsewhere

Comment: also added screenshot to show that just the from method does indeed pick up the DummyDatabase as the type, but loses when I start to use the select method on the builder type: i.e. `new DatabaseContext<DummyDatabase>().with("no", from("bar"))` is correctly typed

Comment: • Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: • For`from("bar").select()` there is no useful context by which `DummyDatabase` exists. You presume that in `with("no", from(x).select(y))`, the compiler can somehow go backwards from the expected type of the second param of `with` all the way back to the type argument called from `from()`. It's not going to work that way. You can manually pass those type arguments as the other answer suggests, or consider refactoring to a different way of calling it entirely. Do you want me to investigate the latter?

Comment: Alright, so I can just assume that there is a depth limit of 1 on any backwards search in typing information then?  I suppose that would be a fair limitation to prevent TS from churning forever evaluating a type.  I was just a bit stuck by the fact that just the from() call alone would infer the type but not after the select, but that would require tracing more than that single step back.

Comment: I think "depth limit of 1" is a reasonable intuition but I've noticed sometimes it seems like zero and other times more than 1.  But generally: inference is some algorithm that has limits, and when you hit the limits you either manually specify the types or you refactor to make inference easier. I'd write up an answer but I see you've already accepted the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```typescript
const b = new DatabaseContext<DummyDatabase>().with("no", from("bar").select(""))
```

with:

```typescript
const b = new DatabaseContext<DummyDatabase>().with("no", from<DummyDatabase, "bar">("bar").select(""))
```

...and after that, the squggly line should now work on `select("")`.

---

The reason it doesn't work is because your function `from` has no way of knowing the database context; what tables are in it and what properties are available within those tables. This means, in fact, that the following code won't error out either:

```typescript
new DatabaseContext<DummyDatabase>().with("no", from("nonexistent_table").select(""))
```

TypeScript won't tell you that the table `nonexistent_table` does not exist!

Now, by adding annotations like in the solution above, function `from` will know the shape of the whole database, so it can tell you the valid properties in the table `bar`.

Comment: I know I can get it if I explicitly type the information, however that's really ugly to have to type every time and the fact that when I start with `from("bar")` it knows the correct type but then loses it is more what I wanted to know if there was a way around.  If the only way is the explicit typing then that's fine I suppose, though I would probably just force usage of the context to build any "from" style queries later since it doesn't need those extra parameters.

Comment: I'm curious though why `new DatabaseContext<DummyDatabase>().with("foo", from("kittens"))` will fail intellisense right now though as the type system knows that `kittens` isn't a valid key until I get to the returned Builder<D, T> which should in theory have the same constraints on table shape...

Comment: @NathanNorthcutt whether To answer your follow up question, I agree it doesn't look neat. Unfortunately I don't think it's possible in TypeScript using "with" style queries.